# Merging rows while updating another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
node1   node2   weight

2          6     1

2          7     1

2          7     1

2          8     1

2         15     1

2         15     1

2         15     1

2         15     1
```

As can be seen from above I want to merge the rows where node1==node2 and update the weight wherever this condition is met so that there is only one row with unique node 1 and node 2 and the weight is the no of occurence of the equality condition.

Sample output is :

```
node 1       node 2        weight 

  2           7               2

  2           15              4
```

and so on.

Comment: Please add the text version.We dont want images

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['node1', 'node2'])['weight'].sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dataframe like

```
   node1  node2  weight
0      2      6       1
1      2      7       1
2      2      7       1
3      2      8       1
4      2     15       1
5      2     15       1
6      2     15       1
7      2     15       1
```

**Option 1 :** groupby sum

```
df.groupby(['node1','node2']).sum().reset_index()
```

```
  node1  node2  weight
0      2      6       1
1      2      7       2
2      2      8       1
3      2     15       4
```

**Option 2** Pivot table with agg func as sum

```
df.pivot_table(index=['node1','node2'],aggfunc=sum).reset_index()
```

```
    node1  node2  weight
0      2      6       1
1      2      7       2
2      2      8       1
3      2     15       4
```

---

If you want group occurance more the once then use filter first then groupby sum i.e

```
ndf = df.groupby(['node1','node2']).filter(lambda x : len(x) > 1)
ndf = ndf.groupby(['node1','node2']).sum().reset_index()
```

```
   node1  node2  weight
0      2      7       2
1      2     15       4
```

Or

```
ndf = df.groupby(['node1','node2']).sum().reset_index()
ndf[ndf['weight'].ne(1)]
```